# Redux reducers aren't updating the store

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I am having bit of a wrinkle with Redux-Saga as the reducers I had done isn't updating the store as it should suppose to do.

I have used Saga to load a static in-app data and then fired the action with the payload passing the data to reducers, I did console.log() to make sure the reducers are getting the payload from action, which they are - but the problem appears to happen when I return the data into the state so that it could be accessible within the components. In props I only get default state from the reducers, any help on this matter would be highly appreciated. Following is the code I am using;

## actions.js

```
    export function loadAppAction() {
      return {
        type: types.LOAD_APP
      }
    }

    export function loadAppDataAction(data) {
      return {
        type: types.LOAD_APP_DATA,
        payload: data
      }
    }
```

## api.js

```
    import appData from '../components/appData';

    export function appDataResponse() {
      return appData;
    }
```

## app.js

```
    export class App extends Component {

      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        const { loadAppAction } = this.props;
        loadAppAction();
      }

      render() {
        const {
          initialLoadData,
          activateModalAction,
          deactivateModalAction,
          toggleModal
        } = this.props;
        console.log('props', this.props)
            return (
          <div className="app">
            {
              toggleModal &&
              <SignInModal
                deactivateModalAction={deactivateModalAction}
              />
            }
          </div>
      }
    }

    function mapStateToProps({ initialLoadReducer, toggleModalReducer }) {
      console.log('lets see', initialLoadReducer);
      return {
        initialLoadData: initialLoadReducer,
        toggleModal: toggleModalReducer
      };
    };

    export default connect(
      mapStateToProps, {
        loadAppAction: actions.loadAppAction,
        activateModalAction: actions.activateModalAction,
        deactivateModalAction: actions.deactivateModalAction,
      })
      (App);
```

## initialLoadReducers.js

```
    export default function (state = [], action) {
      switch (action.type) {
        case types.LOAD_APP_DATA:
          return [...action.payload];
        default:
          return state;
      }
    }
```

## saga - index.js

```
    function* watchLoadAppAction() {
      yield takeEvery(types.LOAD_APP, loadAppSaga);
    }

    export default function* rootSaga() {
      yield all ([watchLoadAppAction()]);
    }
```

## loadAppSaga.js

```
    export default function* loadAppSaga(action) {
      const response = yield call(api.appDataResponse);
      yield put(actions.loadAppDataAction(response));
    }
```

Following is the screenshot of my console for reference [image: Console Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to call loadAppAction when componentDidMount not in the constructor. React doc also suggested the same.

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount

```
export class App extends Component {
   componentDidMount() {
     this.props.loadAppAction();
   }
   ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for bringing this to my attention, much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Right so, I got down to the problem here, I was trying to initialise the app with an empty array which will not going to work anyway, as the component is expecting to receive props from redux which is an empty array. Which is why, React didn't create the DOM at its first run and that caused the app to stop re-rendering even though the props are changing.

To make it work, I now initialise the app with the same data structure but with empty string values and in the next step making the data available through Redux Saga into the reducer and passing it back into the React component.